# Why does this question link auto redirect to an answer?

Tags: discussion, bug

I've stumbled upon this Stack Overflow question link on a blog page. The link is *http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416585/how-to-run-rails-console-on-production-without-executing-spring*. It was about a Ruby on Rails question.

However, clicking on the link placed me to this answer which is totally unrelated, moreover very surprising! *[Previous function, but for two (or more) rows previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415444/previous-function-but-for-two-or-more-rows-previous/3416585#3416585)*

What's happening here?

Answer (score 5):

The correct link would be this: *[How can I run the Ruby on Rails console in production without executing Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316585/how-to-run-rails-console-on-production-without-executing-spring)* which is

> `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316585/how-to-run-rails-console-on-production-without-executing-spring`

Note the addition of a missing digit '3' in the id.

Questions and answers are actually stored in the same underlying table in the Stack Overflow database so the id wins and the given id is actually the id of an answer, not a question.

If we click share on that answer we get

> `https://stackoverflow.com/a/3416585/1038015`

Perhaps if you contact the blog owner, and they will fix the link.

Comment: Aha! What might have happened? They copied the link and somehow missed a 3 ?

Comment: Also note that `https://stackoverflow.com/q/<insert any ID here>` or `stackoverflow.com/a/<insert any ID here>` can redirect to a question or an answer regardless of which is used (so `/q/` can redirect to an answer, and `/a/` can redirect to a question)